# Unable to access MSDN web

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cookies, msdn

I am unable to access any [MSDN web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/), always being redirected to 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/cookie.aspx which shows

> Not Expected

The problem is described [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/problem-with-accessing-microsoft-support/5b8351a2-20e1-4d32-b405-57e6aa2bca50?auth=1) & deleting all cookies is suggested.

But I am quite tired of deleting all the cookies over and over again loosing cached logins as the problem appears anew short while after deleting the cookies. I have tried to selectively delete all the cookies found when searching for `MSDN` text, but it did not help.

What cookie does this problem so that I can delete only the particular cookie?

Comment: Deleting all `Microsoft` cookies worked in Firefox but not in Chrome.

Comment: Deleting cookies with `.microsoft.com` host key directly from database file Cookies helped in Chrome.